# Comments on Post model will not render, no error message displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning and trying to add functionality to a simple app. I'm adding a comments ability to each micropost and creating comments works fine, however the comments will not render. No error message, application runs perfectly fine except the comments partials just isn't included in the final view.

I've looked at similar questions here and tried so many solutions that I'm not even sure where the problem might be, any help would be much appreciated.

I have 3 relevant models: Users, Microposts, Comments.
Microposts belong to Users, has_many comments.
Comments belongs to Microposts and Users.
Comments model includes columns for "comment_content", "micropost_id", "user_id" and "created_at".

**Micropost.rb**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1000 }
acts_as_votable
```

**Comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :micropost
validates :comment_content, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :micropost_id, presence: true
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments
```

**User Controller#show**

```
  def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
@comment = Comment.new
@comments = Micropost.find(params[:id]).comments.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

**Comments Controller#create**

```
  def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.micropost = @micropost
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
     flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
     redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'shared/_comment_form'
  end
end
```

**To render in view from _micropost partial**

```
<ul>
<%= render @comment %>
</ul>
```

**Comments partial _comments**

```
<%= link_to gravatar_for(@micropost.user, size: 15), @micropost.user %>
<%= link_to @micropost.user.name, @micropost.user %>

<% @micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.comment_content %>
<% end %>
```

The comments form displays just fine. After logging in and creating a comment I check the console and confirm a comment is created, has the correct content, is associated with the User that made the post and the micropost it was commented on. 
So the comment is sitting there in the DB, it just won't come out!

**SOLUTION**

**UsersController:**

```
  def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Views**

```
<% @user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
<%= link_to gravatar_for(@user, size: 15), @user %>
<%= link_to @user.name, @user %>


  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.comment_content %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

That's basically it, I was overloading my UsersController#show and that was throwing the whole thing off. As the advice below states the Userscontroller was doing the heavy lifting, and I shouldn't have been defining so many variables there.

Can't express enough thanks to @thedanotto and @fylooi. They were both correct. All of the troubleshooting they walked me through taught me so much. It's intimidating learning Rails and I've always refrained from asking stupid questions online, but this experience showed me just how awesome some people can be! I've got a lot to learn, reading through the pragmatic programmers series, I'll do my best to give back to the community!

Comment: Are you trying to display the comments when you are looking at `micropost#show`? If so could you post that controller.

Comment: @thedanotto I tried rearranging the views by moving the .each loop into the _comments partial itself. With interesting results the Username the first comment is displayed, but nothing else. Gonna follow this and see if it leads anywhere....or is putting the loop into the partial itself bad?

Comment: Your `_comments` partial references `@micropost`. Is `@micropost` defined in the controller for whichever parent view is rendering the partial?

Comment: Also, you need to explicitly `render partial: ` to pass in local variables to a partial. `render` alone does not accept local variables. Note that you can also do `render @comment`, which will use the `_comment` partial to render the `@comment` object (referencing `comment` in the partial - no `@`).

Comment: yes I believe so. The Userscontroller#show is handling the request, and @micropost is defined there. So render doesn't accept the variables. Hmmm, the problem I have is once i change it to "render @comments" in my server log "_comments" partial is never called. I'm trying to figure out why as that may be the root

Comment: It is extremely weird. If I delete the _comment partial, I receive an error "_comment partial not found". However when the file is there, the server logs show its never called. Thus my view doesn't have any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships appear to be set up correctly. This means you can rely upon rails to do most of the heavy lifting in your controller and views.

**User Controller#show** becomes...

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**views/users/show.html.erb** becomes...

```
<% @user.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(@user, size: 15), @user %>
  <%= link_to @user.name, @user %>
  <!-- You have access to micropost here as well, you could still do micropost.user, micropost.user.name instead of @user -->

  <% micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.comment_content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Implemented the changes you suggested, still a no-go. Weird thing is the absence of an error message, according to my logs the _comment partial is never even being called, stops right after rendering the form.

Comment: Sorry about that. What controller method is being called? And could you post that code if you haven't already?

Comment: No problem, I'm trying to learn so any recommendations at all are helping me out a lot, and its using UserController#show, I don't even have a micropost#show defined.

Comment: Ok that's helpful, I'm going to bed, but I'll update my answer when I get up.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll keep at it, maybe I can figure it out before then (doubtful as I'm already on week 2 of trying to solve this lol).

Comment: @OtianEnahs I updated my answer. Hopefully simplifying everything. Worry about pagination after you've got everything functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

this can't work

```
<%= micropost.comment.comment_content %>
```

you have a `has_many` relation in your micropost model.
you could solve this to add a has_one relation to your micropost model with an order by `created_at`

or temporary (really temporary)

```
<%= micropost.comments.last.comment_content %>
```

**update:**

your partial `_comments` just need to talk to the `comment` variable.
so change your `micropost.comment.comment_content` to `comment.comment_content`

the name of the user should `delegate` to the usermodel via

```
delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

in your comment model. now you can use `comment.user_name` to display the name of the user

best

Comment: You're saying my Comments.rb should reflect "has_one :micropost". Could you explain why the "micropost.comment.comment_content" won't work?

Comment: thats because your micropost has a `has_many` relationship, so `micropost` just "return" an array with comments. or did you have an method `comment` in your micropost model?

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. That makes sense, and no I had no method in the micropost model. Still not working but I'll keep trying, thanks for the help.

Comment: @OtianEnahs btw in your partial `_comments` you didnt need micropost. rails will render a `comment` so you just type `comment.comment_content` or `comment.user`

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

You're loading both `User` and `Micropost` in your `UsersController#show` based on ID. Doesn't look right to me, unless your `User` and `Micropost` database IDs move in lockstep.

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
```

A `Micropost` should be shown in a `MicropostsController`, not a `UsersController`. Eg. `/microposts/1` should return the first `Micropost` resource, while `/users/1` returns the first `User` resource.

I'm going to assume you're trying to render the user's `microposts` and their related `comments` from `UsersController#show`

Based on that, your variable structure can be arranged as per the following:

```
# users_controller.rb
class UsersController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts 
    # better practice is to have only one @ instance variable in the   
    # controller, but let's go with this for academic purposes
  end
end


# views/users/show.html.erb
<%= render @microposts %> 

# this can also be written as 
# <% @microposts.each do |micropost| 
#   <%= render partial: 'micropost', locals: { micropost: micropost }
# <% end %>



# views/users/_micropost.html.erb
<%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 15), micropost.user %>
<%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>

<ul> 
  <%= render micropost.comments %>
</ul>


# views/users/_comment.html.erb
<li>
  <%= comment.content
</li>
```